# count based on the index match

Tags: excel, indexing, match

This is my first post.

I am trying to apply the count based on the vlookup but I am struggling to find the solutions. It would really help me out,

if I could get some solution to this. Please find the data for your reference.

[image: Snapshot of requirement]

DATA;

Column A, B and C are fixed range, Row G2 to AK2 are fixed range, Row G3 to AK3 are changeable according to the plan.

For example;

Cover 1 belongs to the LA20, with the type of B27 to match the three ranges from G2 to AK3 return value should be in backward order wise based on the column D4 and E4.

I apply the following array formula in column

```
H16=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(H$15),"",IF(COUNTIF(H$15:$AL$15,"*")<=VLOOKUP(DATA!$G16&H$15,CHOOSE({1,2},DATA!$C$4:$C$11&DATA!$B$4:$B$11,DATA!$D$4:$D$11),2,0),VLOOKUP(DATA!$G16&H$15,CHOOSE({1,2},DATA!$C$4:$C$11&DATA!$B$4:$B$11,DATA!$E$4:$E$11),2,0),"")),"")
```

but its return value wrongly.

```
DATA                
AREA    TYPE    ITEM    COUNT   STATUS
LA20    BP27    COVER-1 4       CD
LA20    BP27    COVER-2 4       CD
LA20    BP27    COVER-3 4       CD
LA23    BP34    COVER-4 5       CD
LA23    BP34    COVER-5 4       CD
LA24    BP34    COVER-6 6       CD
LA26    BP34    COVER-7 6       CD
LA28    BP34    COVER-8 12      CD



    REQUIREMENT                                                                                                                     
AREA    LA01    LA02    LA03    LA04    LA05    LA06    LA07    LA08    LA09    LA10    LA11    LA12    LA13    LA14    LA15    LA16    LA17    LA18    LA19    LA20    LA21    LA22    LA23    LA24    LA25    LA26    LA27    LA28    LA29    LA30    LA32
TYPE    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP27    BP34    BP27    BP27    0   0   0   BP34    0   0   BP34    0   0
COVER-1                                                 CD      CD      CD      CD                                              
COVER-2                                                 CD      CD      CD      CD                                              
COVER-3                                                 CD      CD      CD      CD                                              
COVER-4                                             CD      CD      CD      CD      CD                                          
COVER-5                                                     CD      CD      CD      CD                                          
COVER-6                                     CD      CD      CD      CD      CD      CD                                          
COVER-7                                             CD      CD      CD      CD      CD                      CD                  
COVER-8 CD      CD      CD      CD      CD  CD      CD      CD      CD      CD      CD                      CD
```

Comment: can you edit the requirement table to fewer columns that still illustrate your point?  I am having a hard time understanding you exampl:  "to match the three ranges from G2 to AK3 return value should be in backward order wise based on the column D4 and E4."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Cover-1 is belongs to LA20 with type of BP27, its match the first range in column G4, second ranges to match the row AA2 is LA20 and last ranges match from Z3 is B27 to match from the table from the A4:E11 to update the value CD for 4 columns with reverse order wise.

Second range is important. (AREA) 
I have attached the snapshot for my requirements

Comment: Please help me if

Comment: I must confess I don't comprehend the logic you wish to apply but I thought if I disassemble your formula perhaps I will find your logic. So I arrived at `=CHOOSE({1,2},Data!$C$4:$C$11&Data!$B$4:$B$11,Data!$E$4:$E$11)` and wonder at the meaning. `{1,2}` should always evaluate to `1`. Therefore the function should always return `Data!$C$4:$C$11&Data!$B$4:$B$11`. Is there something I am missing about the CHOOSE() function?

Comment: if there another status beside CD?

Comment: OK I think I may have just figure out the logic.  Please correct me if I am wrong.  Your table on the left called `DATA` is your source information.  Based on that you need to generate the table on the right.  You list out all the possible `AREA` in the format of `LA01` to `LA32` and skip `LA31`.  This identifies the column where you want to start from.  You then want to place the status that corresponds to the `COVER-#` in the previous columns that have a matching type in the form `BP27` or `BP34`  for the number of times equal to to the `COUNT` in the data table.

Comment: P2 and Q2 both have the value of BP34.  Is this correct or should the alternating patern of BP34 then BP27 continue all the way across row 3?

Comment: Is column `LA31` supposed to be missing.  is it possible for `LA20` to have both `BP27` and `BP34`?

Comment: i believe this to be very doable in VBA..not my field of expertise though.  Are you open to a VBA solution?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ed, Apologies for delaying in reply. Row 3 are types (BP34 and BP27), they are changeable on daily basis. There is no LA31. As mentioned Row 3 are changeable. Yes please VBA would do, as long as I get the solution. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Column A4&B4&C4 its exact matches in row Z4 because my starting point is LA20. Please followup my colour code on the snapshot.